# Constructor with mis-typed default value raises no error with GCC 7

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, c++17

In the following code, the variable definition `B<int, int>(14);` should be erroneous:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
};

template<class T, class R=A>
class B {
public:
    explicit B(const int s, R n = A()) { 
        std::cout << "c\n"; 
    }
};

template <class T, class R=A>
void foo(const int s, R nx = A()) {};

int main() {
    B<int, int>(14);
    // foo<int, int>(14);
    // error: could not convert ‘A()’ from ‘A’ to ‘int’
}
```

Why does it cause no compilation error?

I [compiled](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T,+class+R%3DA%3E%0Aclass+B+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++explicit+B(const+int+s,+R+n+%3D+A())+%7B+%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22c%5Cn%22%3B+%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+T,+class+R%3DA%3E%0Avoid+foo(const+int+s,+R+nx+%3D+A())+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++B%3Cint,+int%3E(14)%3B%0A++++//+foo%3Cint,+int%3E(14)%3B%0A++++//+error:+could+not+convert+%E2%80%98A()%E2%80%99+from+%E2%80%98A%E2%80%99+to+%E2%80%98int%E2%80%99%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.154046997389045,l:'4',m:71.89249720044792,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:48.99103139013454,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.00896860986548,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.84595300261096,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) the code with gcc 7.3 and `g++ -std=c++17`

When I compile the code with gcc 7.3 and `g++ -std=c++14`, I get an error.

I thought that line uses the default value for parameter `n` in constructor of `B`.

The default value of `n` is `A()`, which is not convertible to an `int`.

And I should get a compilation error. But that is not the case.

The similar case for function (as tested by `foo`) would cause compilation error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have run into [GCC bug #83020](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83020). Clang 6 and GCC 8 (as well as GCC 6) correctly reject your example code, as does GCC 7 in C++14 mode.

Comment: Wow. That's some bug.